# Getting current session object in Java

Tags: java, session, servlets

Can I access session object from within a function where request object is not present?

I know in Java we access session like this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

But what if we want to access session when request object is not present?

### Is it possible? is there an alternate way to get session object?

Edit

I have a servlet

```
public class ABC extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
             ..........
             ...........
        myFun1(x,y,z);  
    }

      private void myFun1(int x, int y,long z)
      {
            .........
            myFun2(a,b);    
       }

      private void myFun2(int a,String b)
      {
            .........

            //      Need Session here
       }

}
```

Comment: If you don't have the particular request how would you know what session to get?  There could be multiple live sessions in the process.

Comment: Thnaks, I'll pass the request object to functions as an extra parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "when request object is not present". You *could* have a thread-local variable which sets the "current request for this thread" early in the servlet or whatever you're running (you haven't made it clear). Then you could get at "the current request in this thread" from anywhere, and get the session that way. (Or along the same lines, you could set the current *session* instead of the current *request* in the thread-local variable.)

It's not terribly pretty though, and you have problems if you want to do something on a different thread. Passing the request or session down as a dependency is generally cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking though, if you want to access the http session from a place where the request object is not available then you may have design problems in your application and you need to rethink about concerns, layering etc.

Answer (score 1):

passing request object is the solution,

```
public class ABC extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
             ..........
             ...........
        myFun1(x,y,z,req);  
    }

      private void myFun1(int x, int y,long z,HttpServletRequest req)
      {
            .........
            myFun2(a,b,req);    
       }

      private void myFun2(int a,String b,HttpServletRequest req)
      {
            .........

            //      Need Session here
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) technology in to your application you can access everything by calling;

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

Because this is a singleton instance retrieved, you can access it anywhere in your presentation layer.

However, implementing JSF is probably slightly overkill just for this purpose as you'll probably have to make a lot of changes in your configuration and presentation layers to accommodate for it.

That said, if you do decide to go down that road, you can also think about using [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/), which is a fantastic API for those using JSF in their applications.

Comment: It doesn't return a singleton. It returns a threadlocal reference.

Comment: Thank you Balus, I was trying to keep it simple but you are totally right.

Answer (score 0):

We have to configure one listener of type `HttpSessionListener` its method will be called at session creation time and distraction time. If you us this by preparing the object of this class you can get the Session object simply...

Comment: I get a giggle out of "distraction time".